# I can´t remove AzRoleAssignment

Tags: azure, powershell

PS /home/...>

$scope = (Get-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName 'Support Request Contributor (Custom)').Scope

PS /home/...>

PS /home/...>

Remove-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId 'b9f64b24-2220-477c-ae80-92a116ab42d9' -RoleDefinitionName 'Support Request Contributor (Custom)' -Scope $scope

Remove-AzRoleAssignment: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Scope'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: Did you checked the value of $scope? Are you getting the expected value?

Answer (score 0):

Is the assignment on a Subscription, ResourceGroup or Resource. Guessing by the name its on the Subscription. How about you just do like this:

```
Remove-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName john.doe@contoso.com -RoleDefinitionName 'Support Request Contributor (Custom)'
```